# WebAPI Url.Link() returning NULL

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I am having some trouble in generating WebAPI hypermedia links in a project I am working on.

In the code snippet below the extension methods `Order`, `OrderUpdate` and `OrderDelete` for individual orders are all returning Null links.  I suspect this is because WebAPI is unable to resolve these inner routes from the parent `Orders` route.

I am not certain why Null links are being returned as I am supplying valid route names to the `Link` method.

You can see from the resulting JSON output that the `Uri` elements are all `Null` for the `Links` array element within the `Order` object.

```
// WebApiConfig.cs

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Orders",
    routeTemplate: "api/orders",
    defaults: new { controller = "order", action = "get" },
    constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint( HttpMethod.Get ) }
);


config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Order",
    routeTemplate: "api/orders/{orderid}",
    defaults: new { controller = "order" },
    constraints: new { orderid = "^[0-9]+$", httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint( HttpMethod.Get ) }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "OrderUpdate",
    routeTemplate: "api/orders/{orderid}",
    defaults: new { controller = "order", action = "put" },
    constraints: new { orderid = "^[0-9]+$", httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint( HttpMethod.Put ) }
);

// OrderController.cs

public async Task<Orders> Get()
{
    var orders = new Orders();

    orders.Links.OrderList( Url, "self" ); // returns a link OK
    orders.Links.OrderAdd( Url, "order-create" ); // returns a link OK
    foreach ( var order in await _repository.GetOrders() )
    {
        order.Links.Order( Url, "self", order.Id ); // returns NULL
        if ( !User.IsInRole( "Readonly" ) )
        {
            order.Links.OrderUpdate( Url, "order-update", order.Id ); // returns NULL
            order.Links.OrderDelete( Url, "order-delete", order.Id ); // returns NULL
        }
        orders.Order.Add( order );
    }
    return orders;
}

// LinkGenerationExtensions.cs

public static void Order( this List<Link> @this, UrlHelper url, string rel, int orderId )
{
    @this.Add( new Link { Rel = rel, Uri = url.OrderUri( orderId ) } );
}

public static string OrderUri( this UrlHelper url, int orderId )
{
    return url.Link( "Order", new { id = orderId } );
}

public static void OrderList( this List<Link> @this, UrlHelper url, string rel )
{
    @this.Add( new Link { Rel = rel, Uri = url.OrderListUri() } );
}

public static string OrderListUri( this UrlHelper url )
{
    return url.Link( "Orders", new { } );
}

public static void OrderUpdate( this List<Link> @this, UrlHelper url, string rel, int orderId )
{
    @this.Add( new Link { Rel = rel, Uri = url.OrderUpdateUri( orderId ) } );
}

public static string OrderUpdateUri( this UrlHelper url, int orderId )
{
    return url.Link( "OrderUpdate", new { id = orderId } );
}
```

The above code generates the following JSON response:

```
{
    "Order": [
        {
            "Id": 4,
            "OrderRef": 123456,
            "OrderDate": "2015-02-04T10:28:00",
            "CustomerName": "ACME Construction Ltd",
            "OrderedBy": "PA",
            "InstallationDate": "2015-06-15T00:00:00",
            "Address": "900 ACME Street",
            "Postcode": "SW2 7AX",
            "Town": "London",
            "OrderNumber": "6508756191",
            "Value": 525,
            "Invoice": 0,
            "Links": [
                {
                    "Rel": "self",
                    "Uri": null
                },
                {
                    "Rel": "order-update",
                    "Uri": null
                },
                {
                    "Rel": "order-delete",
                    "Uri": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Links": [
        {
            "Rel": "self",
            "Uri": "http://localhost/Site/api/orders"
        },
        {
            "Rel": "order-create",
            "Uri": "http://localhost/Site/api/orders/add"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've answered my own question after discovering that the parameter names in the route values must match those of their defined routes.

Replacing `id` with `orderid` did the job.

Here is the updated code:

```
// LinkGenerationExtensions.cs

public static void Order( this List<Link> @this, UrlHelper url, string rel, int orderId )
{
    @this.Add( new Link { Rel = rel, Uri = url.OrderUri( orderId ) } );
}

public static string OrderUri( this UrlHelper url, int orderId )
{
    return url.Link( "Order", new { orderid = orderId } );
}

public static void OrderList( this List<Link> @this, UrlHelper url, string rel )
{
    @this.Add( new Link { Rel = rel, Uri = url.OrderListUri() } );
}

public static string OrderListUri( this UrlHelper url )
{
    return url.Link( "Orders", new { } );
}

public static void OrderUpdate( this List<Link> @this, UrlHelper url, string rel, int orderId )
{
    @this.Add( new Link { Rel = rel, Uri = url.OrderUpdateUri( orderId ) } );
}

public static string OrderUpdateUri( this UrlHelper url, int orderId )
{
    return url.Link( "OrderUpdate", new { orderid = orderId } );
}

public static void OrderDelete( this List<Link> @this, UrlHelper url, string rel, int orderId )
{
    @this.Add( new Link { Rel = rel, Uri = url.OrderDeleteUri( orderId ) } );
}

public static string OrderDeleteUri( this UrlHelper url, int orderId )
{
    return url.Link( "OrderDelete", new { orderid = orderId } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem on VS2019. Solved when I upgraded the project to .NET5 and all Microsoft nuget packages to v5.x.