# Asp.net core UrlHelper returning nulls

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-webapi

Im  building a simple api with asp.netcore 1.1 and trying to create hypermedia links. I have looked at

[WebAPI Url.Link() returning NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28341042/webapi-url-link-returning-null)

and a couple of similars, but none of those were of help.

my controller is

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/organizers")]
public class OrganizersController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet, Route("{id:int}", Name = "get-organizers")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var uri = Url.Link("default", new {id=2});
            var uri2 = Url.RouteUrl("default", new { controller = "Organizers", action = "get-organizers", id = 1 });
            (...)
        }
        (...)

     }
```

My startup looks like

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        //serilog
        loggerFactory.AddSerilog();

        app.UseMvc(opt=>opt.MapRoute("default", "api/v{version:apiVersion}/{controller}/{action}/{id:int?}"));
        appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => ApplicationContainer.Dispose());
    }
```

i have tried many permutations of the possible parameters including removing action, api, version, etc. still, i get null for both urls.

Comment: Shouldn't the action parameter be "Get" instead of the Routename?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried your example and

```
Url.Link("default", new {id=2});
```

returns `http://localhost:1237/api/v1.0/Organizers/Get/1` and

```
Url.RouteUrl("default", new {controller = "Organizers", action = "get-organizers", id = 1});
```

returns `/api/v1.0/Organizers/get-organizers/1`, even though `get-organizers` action is not defined, it's a route name.

However,

```
Url.Action("Get", new { id = id });
// or
Url.RouteUrl("get-organizers", new { id = id });
```

returns `/api/v1.0/organizers/1`, which looks more RESTful.

You should not be getting `NULL` values. Make sure you have API versioning enabled.

```
    public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddApiVersioning( o => o.ReportApiVersions = true );
    }
```

Comment: i hadnt versioning on.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a url in a couple of ways, [see here for the full documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#url-generation)

Please try this

With `Url.Action`

```
Url.Action("Get", "Organizers", new { id = 1 });
```

With a named route

```
Url.RouteUrl("get-organizers", new {id = 1});
```